# How To Generate Random Post Title Using Different Strings In PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

```html
add_filter('syndicated_item_title', 'fwp_set_title', 10, 2);
function fwp_set_title ($title)
{
   $title1[0] = "Title 1";
   $title1[1] = "Title 2";
   $title1[2] = "Title 3";
   $title1[3] = "Title 4";
   $title1[4] = "Title 5";
   $title1[5] = "Title 6";
   $title1[6] = "Title 7";
   $title1[7] = "Title 8";
   $title1[8] = "Title 9";
   $title1[9] = "Title 10";
   $randomize = rand(0, 9);
   return ($title1[$randomize]);
}
```

So here are the codes. The result of that is it only select from title 1 - 9 which is i dont like. What I want is to generate a title which is from title 1-5 (first word) and next word is from title 6-9 (2nd word)

Example: Hello (from random word of title 1-5) World (From random word of title 6-9)

Please help me modify this one.

Comment: show full code please? add_filter specially

Comment: check from this page. http://adultwebmasterblog.com/tutorials/adult-autoblogs/ 

i want the auto generate title was in 2 different words from random strings

Answer (score 0):

I think i understand what you want so hopefully this is correct.

```
add_filter('syndicated_item_title', 'fwp_set_title', 10, 2);
function fwp_set_title ($title)
{
   $title1[0] = "Title 1";
   $title1[1] = "Title 2";
   $title1[2] = "Title 3";
   $title1[3] = "Title 4";
   $title1[4] = "Title 5";
   $title1[5] = "Title 6";
   $title1[6] = "Title 7";
   $title1[7] = "Title 8";
   $title1[8] = "Title 9";
   $title1[9] = "Title 10";
   $randomize = rand(0, 4); // randomize first 5
   $firstWord = strstr($title1[$randomize], ' ', TRUE); // get first word
   $randomize = rand(5, 9); // randomize last 5
   $secondWord = trim(strstr($title1[$randomize], ' ', FALSE)); // get second word
   echo $firstWord . $secondWord; // output
}
```

The function `strstr` finds the string you are searching for and either returns everything before it or after it.

Read more here: [PHP Docs](https://php.net/strstr)

Comment: i dont know what's the problem but the code you modified did not get the first word same as the second word.

Comment: Sorry if you dont understand. Im not really good in english. Anyway what i really want is this. Example the title of a post is "HELLO WORLD"

"Hello" came from title1 (for example) 
"World" came from title 5 (for example)

So title1 + title2 = hello world.

Sorry i cant explain it correctly.

Comment: Yeah. But when I try to auto post it does not create or select any from the given titles. Instead it comes with its date. Can you please rewrite it with some better codes? I'm working with a Wordpress site. Thanks much.

Comment: im really sorry. you already got my point. It gets two different words from two different titles and puts them together. My problem now is when i put your code in my site it does not generate the two output as title.

Answer (score 0):

or use this function:

```
public static function ipsum($nparagraphs, $wrapper = 'p') {
    $paragraphs = [];
    for ($p = 0; $p < $nparagraphs; ++$p) {
        $nsentences = mt_rand(3, 8);
        $sentences = [];
        for ($s = 0; $s < $nsentences; ++$s) {
            $frags = [];
            $commaChance = .33;
            while (true) {
                $nwords = mt_rand(3, 15);
                $words = self::random_values(self::$lorem, $nwords);
                $frags[] = implode(' ', $words);
                if (self::random_float() >= $commaChance) {
                    break;
                }
                $commaChance /= 2;
            }

            $sentences[] = ucfirst(implode(', ', $frags)) . '.';
        }
        $paragraphs[] = '<' . $wrapper . '>' . implode(' ', $sentences) . '</' . $wrapper . '>';
    }
    return implode($paragraphs);
}

private static function random_float() {
    return mt_rand(0, PHP_INT_MAX - 1) / PHP_INT_MAX;
}

private static function random_values($arr, $count) {
    $keys = array_rand($arr, $count);
    if ($count == 1) {
        $keys = [$keys];
    }
    return array_intersect_key($arr, array_fill_keys($keys, null));
}

private static $lorem = [
    0 => 'lorem',
    1 => 'ipsum',
    2 => 'dolor',
    3 => 'sit',
    4 => 'amet',
    5 => 'consectetur',
    6 => 'adipiscing',
    7 => 'elit',
    8 => 'praesent',
    9 => 'interdum',
    10 => 'dictum',
    11 => 'mi',
    12 => 'non',
    13 => 'egestas',
    14 => 'nulla',
    15 => 'in',
    16 => 'lacus',
    17 => 'sed',
    18 => 'sapien',
    19 => 'placerat',
    20 => 'malesuada',
    21 => 'at',
    22 => 'erat',
    23 => 'etiam',
    24 => 'id',
    25 => 'velit',
    26 => 'finibus',
    27 => 'viverra',
    28 => 'maecenas',
    29 => 'mattis',
    30 => 'volutpat',
    31 => 'justo',
    32 => 'vitae',
    33 => 'vestibulum',
    34 => 'metus',
    35 => 'lobortis',
    36 => 'mauris',
    37 => 'luctus',
    38 => 'leo',
    39 => 'feugiat',
    40 => 'nibh',
    41 => 'tincidunt',
    42 => 'a',
    43 => 'integer',
    44 => 'facilisis',
    45 => 'lacinia',
    46 => 'ligula',
    47 => 'ac',
    48 => 'suspendisse',
    49 => 'eleifend',
    50 => 'nunc',
    51 => 'nec',
    52 => 'pulvinar',
    53 => 'quisque',
    54 => 'ut',
    55 => 'semper',
    56 => 'auctor',
    57 => 'tortor',
    58 => 'mollis',
    59 => 'est',
    60 => 'tempor',
    61 => 'scelerisque',
    62 => 'venenatis',
    63 => 'quis',
    64 => 'ultrices',
    65 => 'tellus',
    66 => 'nisi',
    67 => 'phasellus',
    68 => 'aliquam',
    69 => 'molestie',
    70 => 'purus',
    71 => 'convallis',
    72 => 'cursus',
    73 => 'ex',
    74 => 'massa',
    75 => 'fusce',
    76 => 'felis',
    77 => 'fringilla',
    78 => 'faucibus',
    79 => 'varius',
    80 => 'ante',
    81 => 'primis',
    82 => 'orci',
    83 => 'et',
    84 => 'posuere',
    85 => 'cubilia',
    86 => 'curae',
    87 => 'proin',
    88 => 'ultricies',
    89 => 'hendrerit',
    90 => 'ornare',
    91 => 'augue',
    92 => 'pharetra',
    93 => 'dapibus',
    94 => 'nullam',
    95 => 'sollicitudin',
    96 => 'euismod',
    97 => 'eget',
    98 => 'pretium',
    99 => 'vulputate',
    100 => 'urna',
    101 => 'arcu',
    102 => 'porttitor',
    103 => 'quam',
    104 => 'condimentum',
    105 => 'consequat',
    106 => 'tempus',
    107 => 'hac',
    108 => 'habitasse',
    109 => 'platea',
    110 => 'dictumst',
    111 => 'sagittis',
    112 => 'gravida',
    113 => 'eu',
    114 => 'commodo',
    115 => 'dui',
    116 => 'lectus',
    117 => 'vivamus',
    118 => 'libero',
    119 => 'vel',
    120 => 'maximus',
    121 => 'pellentesque',
    122 => 'efficitur',
    123 => 'class',
    124 => 'aptent',
    125 => 'taciti',
    126 => 'sociosqu',
    127 => 'ad',
    128 => 'litora',
    129 => 'torquent',
    130 => 'per',
    131 => 'conubia',
    132 => 'nostra',
    133 => 'inceptos',
    134 => 'himenaeos',
    135 => 'fermentum',
    136 => 'turpis',
    137 => 'donec',
    138 => 'magna',
    139 => 'porta',
    140 => 'enim',
    141 => 'curabitur',
    142 => 'odio',
    143 => 'rhoncus',
    144 => 'blandit',
    145 => 'potenti',
    146 => 'sodales',
    147 => 'accumsan',
    148 => 'congue',
    149 => 'neque',
    150 => 'duis',
    151 => 'bibendum',
    152 => 'laoreet',
    153 => 'elementum',
    154 => 'suscipit',
    155 => 'diam',
    156 => 'vehicula',
    157 => 'eros',
    158 => 'nam',
    159 => 'imperdiet',
    160 => 'sem',
    161 => 'ullamcorper',
    162 => 'dignissim',
    163 => 'risus',
    164 => 'aliquet',
    165 => 'habitant',
    166 => 'morbi',
    167 => 'tristique',
    168 => 'senectus',
    169 => 'netus',
    170 => 'fames',
    171 => 'nisl',
    172 => 'iaculis',
    173 => 'cras',
    174 => 'aenean',
];
```